# Cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'

Tags: docker, shell, go, webassembly

I am building a Wasm application and to compile it I have a shell script.
When I run it manually from terminal I have the following:

```
/app/Go/assets$ ./script.compile.wasm.sh 
Wasm compiled
```

The content of the file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o ./app.wasm ./wasm.go
echo "Wasm compiled"
```

The wasm file is properly compiled.

But when I run it from Docker I get:

```
Step 15/20 : RUN ./assets/compile.wasm.sh
 ---> Running in 38dd56259b0f
go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'
Wasm compiled
```

The compilation fails.

The Docker line looks like:

```
RUN ./assets/compile.wasm.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local case, you're launching the script from the `assets` directory; in the Dockerfile case you're launching it from its parent directory.  This matters because when the script references files like `./wasm.go`, those are resolved relative to the current directory and not the directory containing the script.

You can resolve this by making sure you're in the `assets` directory in the Dockerfile too:

```sh
# Only for this command; will reset afterwards
RUN cd assets && ./compile.wasm.sh
```

```sh
# For this and all following commands, unless reset with another WORKDIR
WORKDIR /app/Go/assets
RUN ./compile.wasm.sh
```